# how do I set some default value for a check box or a radio button if user do not check the check box or select a button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamically generated form using bootstrap form elements , in which I have options to add check boxes and radio buttons. When I click the submit button, the data in the form is sent to the database as json.
I am using the following javascript function for form submission

```
$('#customForm').on("submit",function(event){
        var formData = JSON.stringify($("#customForm").serializeArray());


        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : formData,
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success:function(data)
            {
            $("#myAlert").show();
            },

            failure:function(error)
            {
            } 
        });
        event.preventDefault();

    });
```

The problem is that , whenever the check box is left unchecked or no option is selected for the radio button, no data is send to the database corresponding to these fields.

Is there any way that I can use to set some default value for these form fields so that I get some value in the database for these fields even if the fields are not selected.

Comment: not really. unchecked checkboxes don't get submitted with the form. there's nothing you can do to change that behavior, other than "silently" checking it for the user. but that's not something you want to do. "Oh, you cleared the checkbox from the 'please spam me' box, we'll just re-check that for you". handle it client-side. `if (!isset($_POST['unusedchecked'])) { ... set some default ...}`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc B's comment, you could also set default values in the database for the fields that would have normally been set differently utilizing the checkboxes.